# Python Regular Expression - Only allow upper and lower characters

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to validate a name in python to just allow upper and lower case letters and I am using the code shown below. This code works and excludes anything extra at the beginning of the string and numbers at the end of the string however it allows things such as 'Ollie@' and I cannot figure out why.
Any help would be appreciated. 
Cheers

```
MatchObjectForename = re.match(r"\b[a-zA-Z]+\b", self.txtForename.get())
print(MatchObjectForename)
if MatchObjectForename == None:
    Incorrect.append(self.txtForename)
else:
    Correct.append(self.txtForename)
```

Comment: Try changing to `r"[a-zA-Z]+$"`. Does it work now?

Comment: It does thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Python RegEx docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), `\b` "Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word", which is not what you want. This will match "Ollie@" because "@" is "after the end of the word", and `\b` matches the empty string between "e" and "@".

Try `r"[a-zA-Z]+$"` instead.

Comment: Again, `^` is redundant here. Check [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#): *If zero or more characters **at the beginning of string** match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject instance.*

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to capture the name part in a group like so: `\b([a-zA-Z]+)\b` and refer to that using group(1).

Answer (score 0):

`\b` indicates the beginning or end of a word. In the example `Ollie@`, the end of `Ollie` is considered the end of a word.

You can try the line start `^` and line end `$` [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refanchors.html); `^[a-zA-Z]+$`

Comment: *You can try the line start `^`* - why?

Comment: It would prevent the same occurring at the beginning of the string i.e. `@Ollie`

Comment: So, what does `re.match` do then?

Comment: It will find matches for that regex in the string but you need to specify that the match must begin with characters in `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#) *If zero or more characters **at the beginning of string** match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject instance.*

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that, I wasn't aware that `re.match` functioned that way. Still, its inclusion would no harm and be useful if OP chose to use `re.search` or another language.

Answer (score 0):

@ is not a "word character" so it counts as a word-boundary.  It probably counts as a special character or punctuation or something.  If you know there is going to be text before and after the name you could match whitespace which might be `\w` in Python, not sure.  If there might be something or nothing on either side of the name you want, it will get more complicated.  You might use one or two regexes to split off the junk and the final one to parse a valid name if needed.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html):

> the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore Unicode character

So you need another way to indicate the end of the word.